# Python Unit Tests - Am I using SetUp wrong?

Tags: python, unit-testing

What am I doing wrong here?

```
import unittest

class Test_1(unittest.TestCase):

    def SetUp(self):
        self.data = []

    def test_data(self):
        self.assertEqual(len(self.data),0)

if __name__=='__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When I run it, it says:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:...\break_unit_test.py", line
>   9 , in test_data
>       self.assertEqual(len(self.data),0) AttributeError: 'Test_1' object has no
>   attribute 'data'

I'm trying to follow [this example](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#basic-example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It must be named `setUp`, starting with a **lowercase** `s`.